# jsessionid ignored

Tags: java, servlets, jsessionid

I'm using a URL with a jsessionid, eg.

http://localhost:8080/myservlet;jsessionid=123

Yet whenever I read the session ID in the HttpServletRequest the value is never 123, but instead a generated session ID, eg. B663A96D3FBC84B4A427C0810EAB9073.

Why is my jsessionid being ignored?

Comment: How did you generate this session ID? Which container do you use (tomcat, etc.)? You can't simply set a JSESSIONID by yourself...

Answer (score 5):

That's because you specified a session ID for which no concrete `HttpSession` object exist in server's memory. In other words, the given session ID is unknown/invalid. You need to specify a session ID which refers a valid and existing `HttpSession` object in server's memory.

Assuming that you **do have** a valid `HttpSession` with ID `B663A96D3FBC84B4A427C0810EAB9073` currently in server's memory, then the following link will work and give the enduser access to exactly that `HttpSession`:

> http://localhost:8080/myservlet;jsessionid=B663A96D3FBC84B4A427C0810EAB9073

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that most application servers these days default to using cookies for session tracking, not URL rewriting. So if your request contains both a session cookie and a JSESSIONID in the URL, it will probably use the one from the cookie. Check the documentation of your appserver for how to configure this.

Comment: Not true. Java servers support both.

Comment: @BastianVoigt My answer said "default to", not "only supports." If a server is configured to use cookie-based session-handling, it's not going to read `jsessionid` from the query string at all, because why would it?

Comment: At least all the java servers that I used (tomcat, glassfish, jboss, and jetty) support both cookies and URL parameters for the jsessionid at the same time by default, afaik they can't be configured to use one or the other.

Comment: Right, and when both are present in a request, what's going to happen? A server can only use one of these methods for any given request, thus it will neccessarily default to only one, and it's very probably going to be the cookie for most clients. Also, literally all of the current servers support configuring this, since it's part of the Java EE API: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setSessionTrackingModes(java.util.Set)

Comment: Ah, now I got your point :) I'm going to edit your answer to make this clearer, hope that's ok with you. Sorry for the misunderstanding